# Get tapped cell in UITapGestureRecognizer handler

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have set up a gesture recognizer for my table cell in my IOS5 app:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* oneFingerDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellOneFingerDoubleTap:)];
oneFingerDoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerDoubleTap];
```

And implemented handler method:

```
- (void)cellOneFingerDoubleTap:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"taptap");
}
```

It works fine. My problem is that I can not pass the cell was tapped or some other data with the tapped cell. As I see (id)sender is the UITapGestureRecognizer itself.

My question is: how can I get the tapped cell in the handler method (cellOneFingerDoubleTap)? How can I get in the handler method the index of the tapped cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you grab the `view` from the gesture recogniser that is passed in to you on your `cellOneFingerDoubleTap:` method, then you'll get the cell that's been tapped. Something like:

```
- (void)cellOneFingerDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)recognizer.view;
}
```

[I'm just assuming by a "cell" you mean a `UITableViewCell` by the way]

Answer (score 0):

UIGestureRecognizer has a

```
-(UIView *)view
```

property that you can use to get the view to which it was attached.

Since you attached the recognizer to a UITableViewCell, pass the recognizer's view to the UITableView's;

```
-indexPathForCell:
```