# Double tap on annotation view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Ok ppl, there **the situation**:

I have annotation markers and when i tap on one of them, it calls the method

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MYCustomAnnotationView *)view`

Then i take some property's values from (MYCustomAnnotationView *)view and, depend on them, do some movements.

I need to do this movements only when annotation is double tapped.

**What did i do:**

1. `UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapOnAnnotationView)];`
   Failed because i need to send         `(MYCustomAnnotationView *)view`. I tried to store last hitted annotation, but it not seems to be right way.
2. `UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] performSelector:@selector(doubleTapOnAnnotationView:mapView:) withObject:view withObject:mapView];`
   but it not works.
3. `tapCount++;
   switch (tapCount)
   {
       case 1: //single tap
           [self performSelector:@selector(singleTap:) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0.2];
           break;
       case 2: //double tap
           [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTap:) object:nil];
           [self performSelector:@selector(doubleTap:) withObject: nil];
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
   if (tapCount>2) tapCount=0;`
   but it not works with this method properly.

I think i need something like completionHandler, when double tap. Maybe somebody knows what can help in this situation?

Comment: You can access the view that handled the tap gesture: `-(void)doubleTapOnAnnotationView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap{MyCustomAnnotationView *annotationView = tap.view;}`, and use `@selector(doubleTapOnAnnotationView:)`

Comment: This is the right answer. Works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get tapped cell in UITapGestureRecognizer handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203610/get-tapped-cell-in-uitapgesturerecognizer-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In `-mapView viewForAnnotation`

```
if ([annotationView gestureRecognizers] == nil) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapOnAnnotationView:)];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [annotationView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
```

2)

```
-(void)doubleTapOnAnnotationView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
MYCustomAnnotationView *view = (MYCustomAnnotationView*)tap.view;
...
}
```

Thanks to **Larme**.